# Unable to LoadLibrary 'kernel32.dll'. When invoked from WCF service

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, loadlibrary, kernel32

Native methods class looks like this

```
    static class NativeMethods
    {    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
    }
```

Loading the dll from a local path using app.config

```
 IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDll"]);
```

These methods are implemented inside a class library and can be invoked from a Windows forms Application as well as WCF Service.

When we invoke the above method from Win forms it works fine. Please find the snapshot below.
[image]

When we invoke the above method from a WCF web service it fails to load dll and it also does not throw any error. Please find the snapshot below.
[image]

We have checked to see if its a problem with permissions, but it was of no help.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: You aren't loading `kernel32.dll`. You are loading `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDll"]`. Do some debugging next. Start by reading the documentation of `LoadLibrary`. Which tells you how errors are handled. If `NULL` is returned, that means the function failed, and you need to call `GetLastError` to find out why. For p/invoke you need to use `SetLastError = true` and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`, or `throw new Win32Exception();` You'll want to know the value of `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDll"]` also. Again, do some debugging.

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDll"] contains value.. I have checked for all possible basic errors but was not able to find an answer.

Comment: You didn't do what I described

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion David. I tried loading kernel32.dll. But the issue seems to be a little different and strange.

Comment: We created a new project with as a "WCF service application" and it works fine.  If the project type is "WCF service library" then it does not load the dll handle.

Comment: I don't understand why you are ignoring my advice. Anyway, there seems little point in my giving it if you don't want it. You won't make progress this way.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the LastError to see, what happens:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);
```

If the DllHandle is zero, you can obtain the last error with

```
Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString();
```

This call is from faaar far depths of my memory, I am currently not able to test in a VS environment, but it should be close to truth.

I can also remember, that you need Full trust for the Project/Setting in IIS. Not 100% sure on this one, though.

Comment: Tried with above suggestion. Unfortunately it did not return any error. We are still not able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We created a new project with as a "WCF service application" and it works fine.

If the project type is "WCF service library" then it does not load the dll handle.

we are still not sure why this behavior is exhibited in WCF.

Presently to solve this issue we have created a new "WCF service application".